# JSP Get Value of Property

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, scriptlet, usebean

I am very new to JSPs so I need your help.  Google didn't give me what I was looking for, I might just entered the wrong search term.  So please forgive me, but I think its a really dumb question, however nothing seems to be on the net about it.

I created a login screen (works fine) and the credentials are checked (works fine) and the main screen gets a DTO which should be evaluated.

As you can see, there is a jsp:getProperty tag, it works fine, if I try to access the paramter name using jsp:getProperty.  I want to do some additional checks, therefor I tried to access the property within the <% %> section, in there however, it is null.  Is there a way how to access the object within the <<% %> section, after you retrieved it with a jsp:useBean tag?

Here is the main jsp file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
 <%@ page import="de.daniel.docmanager.dto.User"  %>   
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <jsp:useBean id="user" class="de.daniel.docmanager.dto.User" scope="session">  
 </jsp:useBean>

<%
String name =  user.getName();
System.out.println("name: " + name);  //<= name is null
%>

Hello <jsp:getProperty property="name" name="user"/> //<= works fine
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your support. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Avoid Scriptlets and useBean , Go for EL and JSTLs !

Comment: okay, nice idea, but can you give me a hint?  I want to check, if the user object is set, if not, I want a redirect to the login page. How would you do it?

Comment: You can do it using simple Servlet or even a Filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice to use *scriptlets* in JSP . Read this nice [SO Q&A : How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?lq=1) on this subject .

---

Coming back to your problem. You are defining a bean using *Standard Action* as :

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="de.daniel.docmanager.dto.User" scope="session">  
</jsp:useBean>
```

The `useBean` tag will look for an instance of the *"de.daniel.docmanager.dto.User"* class in the `session` .  If the instance is not already there, it will create a new instance of *"de.daniel.docmanager.dto.User"* , and put it in the `session`.

You have to retrieve the object from the `session` scope :

```
<%
 String name =  ((de.daniel.docmanager.dto.User)session
                                      .getAttribute("user")).getName();
 System.out.println("name: " + name);  
%>
```

> I want to do some additional checks, therefor I tried to access the property within the <% %> section

You can use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) or some tag library for that purpose.

Comment: Thank a lot guys - you saved my night.  I really appreciate it.